# Spring @Autowired session bean

Tags: java, spring, session, jsf-2, autowired

I have a session scoped user bean:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class UserBean {
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

and an address bean:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class AddressBean {


    @Autowired
    private UserBean userBean;

    public getUserBean(){
          return userBean;
    }

    public void setUserBean(UserBean userBean){
          this.userBean=userBean;
    }
 }
```

When I call UserBean in JSF its fine and I can see an object has been instantiated. When I call AddressBean...the UserBean is always null and has not been injected. How can I wire this up properly?

Comment: Can you post associated XML configurations? And you be more clear what do u mean by calling in JSF?

Comment: Please, show the definition of `CurrentUserBean`

Comment: Sorry meant UserBean...fixed my post

Comment: Do you have the `<context:component-scan base-package="your bean package"/>` and `<context:annotation-config />` in your applicationContext.xml?

Comment: Are you sure that `AddressBean` is instantiated before `UserBean`?Are you getting null pointer or Bean creation Exception?